# Shared ViewModels in modules

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I have an Activity with multiple fragments under it. I want to share data with the Shared ViewModel, but they are all in different Modules. I can't get the ActivityViewModel Class. When I received activityViewModels() using CoreViewModel, the parent of ActivityViewModel, I got an object that was different from what I received with ActivityViewModel，How can I Share ViewModel in multiple Modules

This is the log I printed after I moved them to the same Module，But that's not the way I wanted it done

In MainActivity

```
 extend ->MainViewModel:CoreViewModel:ViewModel
 val mV0 by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
 LogD("mViewModel0 = $mV0")
```

In MineFragment(The Fragment is MainActivity child,To get MainViewModel.class I moved MineFragment to the same module as MainActivity)

```
 val mV1 by activityViewModels<MainViewModel>()
 val mV2 by activityViewModels<CoreViewModel>()
 LogD("mViewModel1 = $mV1")
 LogD("mViewModel2 = $mV2")
```

Log info

```
mViewModel0 = com.nf.bitcoinexchange.activities.main.MainViewModel@6505362
mViewModel1 = by activityViewModels<MainViewModel>()= com.nf.bitcoinexchange.activities.main.MainViewModel@6505362
mViewModel2 = by activityViewModels<CoreViewModel>()= com.nf.corelib.viewmodel.CoreViewModel@3290057
```

The translation software I use may be a little unclear... sorry

Comment: Are you using same fragment with different module activity? Share more info

Comment: i add more info ,thanks

Comment: I couldn't understand... What your expecting... Shared viewmodels based on activity LifeCycle untill the activity destory you'll receive update... If you're rendering fragments inside main activity that fragments can receive same data. If it's different activity means based on that activity

Comment: Now what happens is that if I use MainViewModel's parent class(activityViewModels<CoreViewModel>()) to receive the object, it doesn't match the object that I use MainViewModel(activityViewModels<CoreViewModel>()) to receive,in same fragment ,same lifecycle ,same time